# android databinding error runtime/compiler

Tags: android, kotlin, compiler-construction, runtime, android-databinding

Someone knows how to fix this: ANTLR Tool version 4.7.1 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.5 ?

I tried this "solution" but didn't work for me

```
configurations.all() {
        resolutionStrategy.force "org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.5.3"
        resolutionStrategy.force "org.antlr:antlr4-tool:4.5.3"
    }
```

I also tried changing to 4.7.1 but didn't work

Dependecies I use:

```
mplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlinVersion"

implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$supportVersion"
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$supportVersion"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$supportVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$materialVersion"
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$version_constraint_layout"

implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycleVersion"
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycleVersion"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion"
implementation "androidx.room:room-coroutines:$roomVersion"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"


ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'
ext.version_gradle = '3.6.3'
ext.kotlinVersion = '1.3.0'
ext.coroutineVersion = '1.0.1'
ext.supportVersion = '1.0.0'
ext.materialVersion = '1.0.0-alpha1'
ext.lifecycleVersion = "2.0.0"
ext.roomVersion = "2.1.0-alpha03"
ext.version_room = '2.2.5'
ext.version_navigation = '1.0.0'
ext.version_constraint_layout = "2.0.0-alpha3"
```

full error:

```
:app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED ANTLR Tool version 4.7.1 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.5.3ANTLR Runtime version 4.7.1 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.5.3 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

Comment: Same thing tried the configurations.all and it fails to build.  But was successful once I upgraded it ti 4.7.1